# Two applications(*.exe) using same data pointers from data DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, wxwidgets, shared

I have a huge program (A) which uses about 30 (most of my own, some 3rd party) dll´s. It uses ActiveX, ATL and MFC to do different stuff. Now i want to use wxWidgets for some special tasks and will call the wxWidgets dialogs from within the program. I can do this with a special designed DLL which takes the wxW.. parts. But to run the special tasks with or without the A programm i would to like to put the wxW.. stuff in an exe (B) and these exe should address the same data from the A program. As far as i know each *.exe has its own process and so i can not share the same pointer address.

I can put in some shared data block in one of the DLLs.

```
#pragma data_seg("SHARED")  
    CClassA  *g_ClassAPointer=NULL;
#pragma data_seg()  
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:SHARED,RWS")
```

If the A is running and starts B, i can get the pointer g_ClassAPointer with the address within A. Is there a way to get the address or get an offset to reach this address within B ?

Thanks in advance,

Howie

BTW: We also want to use wxWidgets to fade all the MFC stuff more and more to cross platform code otherwise i would stick to MFC or use the wxW - DLL within a wrapper *.exe.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for shared memory, and the usual way to create that is via `CreateFileMapping`. This can create shared memory backed by a named file, or backed by the paging file. (Memory allocated by `GlobalAlloc`  is also backed by the paging file, so that's no unusual thing).

In either case, the memory block from `CreateFileMapping` is named, so another process can access the shared memory block by calling `OpenFileMapping` with the same name.

Keep in mind that the shared memory block might reside at different offsets in memory. Also, if you put `CClassA` in shared memory, there's no automatic mechanism to ensure that all pointers inside `CClassA` point to the same shared memory block. E.g. putting a `std::string` or MFC `CString` in shared memory is unlikely to achieve what you intended.

Comment: ok. Thanks for your reply. I will look for the GlobalAlloc stuff. I used Filemappings for some multiprocess logging stuff some years ago.

Comment: @howieh: Eh, `GlobalAlloc` is not what you need. That's the normal Windows allocation method behind e.g. `new` and `malloc`. You need `CreateFileMapping`.